# Jenkins installation issue through Ansible playbook

Tags: jenkins, ansible, cloudbees

I have written ansible playbook to install cloudbees jenkins in our production VM's. While running ansible playbook for the first time, it got successful but jenkins not up and running and same playbook running in second time jenkins up and running fine.

I have manually downloaded jenkins.war(2.138.x) and moved to VM. While running ansible playbook for the first time it is executed successfully, but the jenkins is not up and running, so i went inside vm and checked jenkins home directory. It is only showing one folder i.e WAR, but while running the same playbook for the second time the jenkins is up on running and again i have logged into Vm and checked jenkins home directory. Now i can able to see all configuration files inside home directory.i have checked the logs what i have observed is first time while running the jvm lines is not taken. but while running second time i have observed some jvm related lines.But i have installed java and i set environment variables as well.

```
   - hosts: all
     become: true
     become_user: user1

     tasks:

     - name: installing the jenkins
       shell: nohup java -DJENKINS_HOME=/user1/jenkins -jar /user1/jenkins.war &
```

I am expecting the cloudbees jenkins installation for first time only, while running the Ansible-playbook

Comment: What is the result if you run jenkins manually without ansible ?

Comment: you should not use nohup for running jenkins. you should have used the packages. Seems like the nohup exit(If exited) was not captured by ansible as it was ran in the background. If you can re-create get the nohup.out content and post it here.

Comment: @Nelson, While running jenkins manually,  everything is perfect, it means jenkins up and running and nohup. out also creating in VM's

Comment: @error404,  Unable to find the nohup. out file, after run running the ansible playbook for installing jenkins

Comment: How to run the applications in background by using ansible playbook?... Without using nohup

Comment: ideally it should be in /user1/ directory. Also use command instead of shell module. provide args: chdir instead of specifying the absolute path

Comment: Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.Error: Properties init: Could not determine current working directory.
        at java.lang.System.initProperties(Native Method)
        at java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass(System.java:1166)

Comment: This is the logs for jenkins installation, while running the ansible playbook

Comment: these error refers to with directory not present from where the command was executed at that time. Can you update the description with the updated playbook i.e using command with args module. Also you should specify the full path of the java binary

Answer (score 0):

```
- hosts: all
  become: true
  become_user: user1

  tasks:

    - name: installing the jenkins
      shell: cd /user1 ; nohup java -DJENKINS_HOME=/user1/jenkins -jar jenkins.war &
```

First change the current directory to your jenkins war file directory and then run the nohup command in remote server